# Open new window in Ionic sidemenu app without back button

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a big problem. I'm working on a side menu app, and i need to open another view from another view. I tried to use $state.go and $location.go but when i open a window, this window have the back button of the navigation bar. I want the window will open like when i click on a item on my menu, so with the sidemenu icon on left of the nav-bar. What is the method to open a "new window"?

when i open the new view with AngularJS $state.go and $location.path:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNtMI.png)

when i open the same with href="url" in my HTML sidemenu :

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osymo.png)

I need to open the new view like the second screenshot using angularJS. How can i hit it?

Comment: What do you mean with "open new window in Ionic sidemenu app"? Ionic apps are generally Single Page Apps... only one window... Please explain.

Comment: yea, sorry. So: with window i mean a new view. When i open a new view with $state and $location, the new view is opened but the nav bar on left display the "back button". I want open this new view like when i open it from the side menu, so on the left of my nav bar i have the menu button. Now i upload my original post with some screens

Comment: It's also a good practice to provide a minimal verifiable example...

Comment: i added the screenshots now. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need navigation back button (eventually on condition) you can use this code in your index.html:

```
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button hide-back-button="{{options.hideBackButton}}">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
```

When you need to hide the back button set `options.hideBackButton = false;`

Another way is to use: [`$ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/#showBackButton)